# Variation of determinant of the metric tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor

I have the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. I want to make the variation of $\sqrt{-g}$ where $g=detg_{\mu\nu}$.

How can I make this work? My attempt is the following:

$$\sqrt{-g}=\sqrt{-e^{Tr(log(g_{\mu\nu}))}}=\sqrt{-e^{-Tr(log(g^{\mu\nu}))}}$$

$$\rightarrow\delta\sqrt{-g}=\delta(\sqrt{-e^{-Tr(log(g^{\mu\nu}))})}=\delta(-e^{-\frac{1}{2}Tr(log(g^{\mu\nu}))})$$

$$=e^{-\frac{1}{2}Tr(log(g^{\mu\nu}))}\delta(-\frac{1}{2}Tr(log(g^{\mu\nu})))=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\delta g^{-1}Tr((log(g^{\mu\nu})))=$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}Tr(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu})=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\ g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}$$

But, there seems to be a problem of notation; I write $Tr(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu})$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming the final equality $-\sqrt{-g}g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}/2$ is a known result you are trying to check against your calculation of $-\sqrt{g}\ \text{tr}(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu})/2$.  If so, you have essentially arrived at the same result, but notice that the expression $g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}$ in your final equality is already a scalar, since there is an [implied sum over repeated indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). Taking the trace of such a quantity is trivial since there is only one element. Actually, what you have in the last equality is *already* the trace that you probably intended since for a matrix product $g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\nu\rho}$ the trace is given by summing over the remaining free indices $\mu$ and $\rho$:
$$
\text{tr} \left(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\nu\rho}\right) =  g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\nu\mu}=g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}
$$

---

I'll also add that there is an easier way to do the calculation in your question. Namely, you could use [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) for invertible matrices, which gives that for an invertible matrix $A$:
$$
d \det A = \det A \ \text{tr}\left(A^{-1} dA\right) \ .
$$
In terms of the variation of the metric tensor this means you can quickly find that $\delta g = g \left(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}\right)$, which lets you compute
$$
\delta\sqrt{-g} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{-g}}\delta g= \frac{1}{2}\frac{-g}{\sqrt{-g}}\left(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\left(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand now my error: I wrote wrong the matrix product in the final line.

Comment: OK great, no problem. If what I provided was helpful in answering your question, consider giving it your vote as well.

Comment: I tried to give it, but I haven't much reputation. For now I can give only my thank you! In the future I will remember to put the vote